# Integrating Workflow In liferay custom portlet not working

Tags: model-view-controller, liferay, workflow, portlet

Hi all again I hava a custom portlet  with a single table in service builder. I want to integrate workflow so that insertion of row in the table should go through kaleo workflow so i didn't found a clear tutorial except that one http://liferayzone.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/kaleo-workflow-configuration-for-custom-portlet-in-liferay-6-1/

to have added custom code but when i run an instert item trought the form it get displayed on on a jsp that list all item inserted. the workflow integration didn't worked an nothing got displayed on My Workflow Task. Before doing this i enabled Workflow for my deployed portlet in the control panel.

here is my service builder entity

```
<author>Cooder</author>
    <namespace>sem</namespace>
    <entity name="OrganizationType" local-service="true" uuid="true">
        <column name="organizationTypeId" primary="true" type="long"></column>
        <column name="organizationTypeName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="status" type="int"></column>
        <column name="statusByUserId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="statusByUserName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="statusDate" type="Date"></column>
        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="createDate" order-by="desc"></order-column>
        </order>
        <finder name="OrganizationTypeName" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="organizationTypeName"></finder-column>
        </finder>
        <finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
        <finder name="CompanyId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="companyId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
        <finder name="G_S" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
            <finder-column name="status"></finder-column>
        </finder>
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portal" entity="User"></reference>
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" entity="AssetEntry"></reference>
    </entity>
```

Next is my custum organizationImpl class

```
public class OrganizationTypeLocalServiceImpl
    extends OrganizationTypeLocalServiceBaseImpl {
    /*
     * NOTE FOR DEVELOPERS:
     *
     * Never reference this interface directly. Always use {@link sem.service.service.OrganizationTypeLocalServiceUtil} to access the organization type local service.
     */

    public OrganizationType addOrganizationType(long userId, String organizationTypeName, ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException, SystemException{
        User user = userPersistence.findByPrimaryKey(userId);
        long organizationTypeId = counterLocalService.increment(OrganizationType.class.getName());
        OrganizationType organizationType = organizationTypePersistence.create(organizationTypeId);
        Date now = new Date();

        organizationType.setGroupId(user.getGroupId());
        organizationType.setCompanyId(user.getCompanyId());
        organizationType.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        organizationType.setStatus(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_DRAFT);
        organizationType.setCreateDate(serviceContext.getCreateDate(now));
        //organizationType.setModifiedDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate(now));

        organizationType.setOrganizationTypeName(organizationTypeName);

        //super.addOrganizationType(organizationType);
        organizationTypePersistence.update(organizationType, false);

        assetEntryLocalService.updateEntry(
                serviceContext.getUserId(), 
                serviceContext.getScopeGroupId(),
                OrganizationType.class.getName(),
                organizationType.getOrganizationTypeId(),
                serviceContext.getAssetCategoryIds(),
                serviceContext.getAssetTagNames());

        WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(
                organizationType.getCompanyId(),
                organizationType.getGroupId(),
                organizationType.getUserId(), 
                OrganizationType.class.getName(),
                organizationType.getPrimaryKey(),
                organizationType, serviceContext);

        /*resourceLocalService.addResources(organizationType.getCompanyId(), 
                organizationType.getGroupId(),
                organizationType.getUserId(),
                OrganizationType.class.getName(),
                organizationType.getOrganizationTypeId(),
                false,
                true,
                true);*/

        return organizationType;
    }

    public OrganizationType updateMyOrganizationType(long userId, long organizationTypeId, String organizationTypeName, ServiceContext serviceContext) throws PortalException, SystemException{

        User user = userPersistence.findByPrimaryKey(userId);
        Date now = new Date();

        OrganizationType orgType = OrganizationTypeLocalServiceUtil.fetchOrganizationType(organizationTypeId);

        orgType.setModifiedDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate(now));
        orgType.setGroupId(user.getGroupId());
        orgType.setCompanyId(user.getCompanyId());
        orgType.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        orgType.setOrganizationTypeName(organizationTypeName);

        super.updateOrganizationType(orgType);

        return orgType;
    }

    public OrganizationType getOrganizationType(long organizationTypeId) throws PortalException, SystemException{
        return organizationTypePersistence.findByPrimaryKey(organizationTypeId);
    }
    public List<OrganizationType> getOrganizationTypeAll() throws SystemException{
        return organizationTypePersistence.findAll();
    }

    public OrganizationType deleteOrganizationType(OrganizationType organizationType) throws SystemException, PortalException{
        assetEntryLocalService.deleteEntry(OrganizationType.class.getName(), organizationType.getOrganizationTypeId());
        return organizationTypePersistence.remove(organizationType);
    }

    public OrganizationType deleteOrganizationType(long organizationTypeId) throws PortalException, SystemException{
        OrganizationType orgType = organizationTypePersistence.findByPrimaryKey(organizationTypeId);
        return deleteOrganizationType(orgType);
    }

    public OrganizationType updateStatus(
            long userId,
            long resourcePrimKey,
            int status,
            ServiceContext serviceContext) throws SystemException, PortalException{
        User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);
        OrganizationType orgType = OrganizationTypeLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationType(resourcePrimKey);
        orgType.setStatus(status);
        orgType.setStatusByUserId(userId);
        orgType.setStatusByUserName(user.getFullName());
        orgType.setStatusDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate());
        organizationTypePersistence.update(orgType, false);
        if(status == WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED){
            assetEntryLocalService.updateVisible(OrganizationType.class.getName(), resourcePrimKey, true);
        }
        else{
            assetEntryLocalService.updateVisible(OrganizationType.class.getName(), resourcePrimKey, true);
        }
        return orgType;
    }
}
```

Next is my AssetRendererFactory

```
public class RendererFactoryOrganizationTypeAsset extends BaseAssetRendererFactory{

    @Override
    public AssetRenderer getAssetRenderer(long classPK, int type)
            throws PortalException, SystemException {
        OrganizationType organizationType = OrganizationTypeLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationType(classPK);
        return new AssetRendererOrganizationType(organizationType);
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return OrganizationType.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "article";
    }

}
```

Next is my AssetRenderer

```
public class AssetRendererOrganizationType extends BaseAssetRenderer{

    private OrganizationType _organizationType;
    @Override
    public long getClassPK() {
        return _organizationType.getOrganizationTypeId();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId() {
        return _organizationType.getGroupId();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSummary(Locale arg0) {
        return _organizationType.getOrganizationTypeName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(Locale arg0) {
        return "Organization type context entry";
    }

    @Override
    public long getUserId() {
        return _organizationType.getUserId();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUuid() {
        return _organizationType.getUuid();
    }

    @Override
    public String render(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, String template)
            throws Exception {
        if (template.equals(TEMPLATE_FULL_CONTENT)) {
            return "/html/organizationType.jsp";
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public AssetRendererOrganizationType(OrganizationType _organizationType) {
        super();
        this._organizationType = _organizationType;
    }

}
```

Next is my WorkflowHandler

```
public class WorkflowHandlerOrganizationType extends BaseWorkflowHandler{

    public static final String CLASS_NAME = OrganizationType.class.getName();

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return CLASS_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Locale locale) {
        return LanguageUtil.get(locale, "model.resource.", CLASS_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public Object updateStatus(int status, Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext)
            throws PortalException, SystemException {
        long userId = GetterUtil.getLong((String) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID));
        long resourcePrimKey = GetterUtil.getLong((String) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext) workflowContext.get("serviceContext");
        return OrganizationTypeLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(userId, resourcePrimKey, status, serviceContext);
    }

}
```

finally Here is the piece of  liferay-portlet deployment descriptor

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>SearchEngineManager</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <asset-renderer-factory>sem.RendererFactoryOrganizationTypeAsset</asset-renderer-factory>
        <workflow-handler>sem.WorkflowHandlerOrganizationType</workflow-handler>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>
            /js/main.js
        </footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>
            searchenginemanager-portlet
        </css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
```

please help me to figure out what is missing. I'm using MVCPorltet in liferay 6.1 GA3 with Kaleo workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havn't added any error log, so its very difficult to find the error. Why don't you try these two links

http://www.cignex.com/articles/applying-advanced-workflow-custom-assets-liferay-6
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11117796

Also you can find a sample project over here.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/meeralferay/files/LiferayWorkFlowPortlet/

You want to have Organization entity handled with the workflow. But you have implemented, the workflow level services in `cm.egov.cameroon.sem.service.service.impl.OrganizationTypeLocalServiceImpl.addOrganizationType(long, String, ServiceContext`)

on place of

`cm.egov.cameroon.sem.service.service.impl.OrganizationLocalServiceImpl.addOrganization(String, String, long, ServiceContext).`

Comment: Hi thank for the demo LiferayWorkFlowPortlet it worked with my kaleo workflow. doing the same thing in my custom portlet but nothing is displayed in the workflow task. data submited are immediately displayed to de view.jsp. the jsp view provide a from to imput oganizationTypeName and display the list of all organizationTypeName inserted. data i submited should be valided by workflow before being displayed on the jsp view: this isn't de case. there is nothing going wrong in the eclipse console. please help me to debug my project

Comment: Everything is ok the problem was in the method addOrganizationType